# How stop yasnippet field in emacs 24

Tags: python, emacs, yasnippet

I use elpy and yasnippet to make emacs become a python editor.

Then I use yasnipprt to build a class object, but I find I can't exit field as quickly as sublime text can, within double "return". That means I have to move cursor at the begin of line used tab or keyboard one by one at the end of class object, and type new code in, then I can exit class field which yasnippet supported.

Have anyone had same confusion about exit field?

I push init.el code below, and what is the key that exit field of yasnippet?

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
       '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

;;;(add-to-list 'package-archives
;;;      '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))

(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)

(add-to-list 'load-path
       "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

(c-add-style
"python-new"
'((indent-tabs-mode . 4)
(fill-column      . 78)
(c-basic-offset   . 4)
(c-offsets-alist  . ((substatement-open . 0)
         (inextern-lang . 0)
         (arglist-intro . +)
         (knr-argdecl-intro . +)))
(c-hanging-braces-alist . ((brace-list-open)
                 (brace-list-intro)
                 (brace-list-close)
                 (brace-entry-open)
                 (substatement-open after)
                 (block-close . c-snug-do-while)))
(c-block-comment-prefix . "* "))
)

;; This is a very crude hook that auto-selects the C style depending on
;; whether it finds a line starting with tab in the first 3000 characters
;; in the file
(defun c-select-style ()
(save-excursion
    (if (re-search-forward "^\t" 3000 t)
   (c-set-style "python")
    (c-set-style "python-new"))))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'c-select-style)
```

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you asking how to jump between fields while expanding a snippet?

Comment: I am so sorry about my poor english and thanks for your patience. I'd like to ask jump out fields (I think it's same meaning by yours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking how to jump between fields in yasnippet.

- To jump to the next field press `TAB` (`yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand`)
- To jump to the previous field, press `S-TAB` (`yas-prev-field`)
- To delete a field and move to the next field, use `C-d` (`yas-skip-and-clear-or-delete-next-char`)